# Музыка как в VK

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Подскажите, как сделать на сайте музыку, что-бы не пропадала при обновлении страницы.(как в социальных сетях)??

Comment: Мб сохранять в локальном хранилище название и промежуток?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВК является одностраничным приложением (SPA), тоесть на нём не происходит фактических переходов по страницам, а вместо этого: меняется URL в адресной строке, создаётся новая запись в истории браузера, JSом генерируется новая страница и налету заменяет собой предыдущую. В таком приложении могут быть статичные элементы, не затрагиваемые в вышеупомянутых процессах. Плеер является одним из таких элементов и потому не прекращает играть, сколько бы ты не перемещался по сайту.

Чтобы сделать плеер как в ВК, нужно сначала научиться делать сайты типа ВК. А там уже потом подойдёт абсолютно любой плеер.